NesxJS reinitialise .ts module
I'm using nextjs and when I'm in the dev environment I think the fast reload reset me this map. (when I build it and I start it in production mode, this resolve the problem)
const downloadTokens = new Map<string, string>(); console.log("instance created") export default downloadTokens;
do u have some ideas?
this map is going to be called from this nextjs handler:
import * as fs from 'fs';
import {NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse} from "next";
import {getProductCode} from "@/store/schematic/DownloadToken";

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    if (req.method != 'GET')
        return res.status(400).json({status: 400, messages: "Invalid method, instead make a get request!"})

    const downloadToken = req.headers['authorization'];
    if (!downloadToken)
        return res.status(400).json({status: 400, messages: "Invalid token!"})

    const productCode = getProductCode(downloadToken as string);
    const fileName = `${productCode}.schematic`

    const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(`${process.cwd()}/data/schematics/${fileName}`);
    if (fileBuffer.length == 0)
        return res.status(500).json({status: 500, messages: "Unable to find the schematic file. Please contact the administrator."})
    const blob = Buffer.from(fileBuffer);

    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename=${fileName}`)
    return res.status(200).send(blob);
}

and there are the DownloadToken functions
import {randomUUID} from "node:crypto";
import downloadTokens from "./DownloadTokenMap";
console.log(`downloadTokens instance : ${downloadTokens}`);

export function generate(productCode: string): string {
    const token = randomUUID();
    downloadTokens.set(token, productCode);
    console.log(downloadTokens)
    return token;
}

export function getProductCode(token: string): string | null {
    const productCode = downloadTokens.get(token);
    console.log(downloadTokens)
    return productCode ? productCode : null;
}

DEBUG
 ✓ Compiled /api/capture in 111ms (145 modules)
instance created
downloadTokens instance : [object Map]
Map(1) {
  'b85801bd-6e9c-4af7-aa4a-35d5530b5ed9' => 'SC-SKYBLOCK_LOBBY-1'
}
 POST /api/capture?orderId=xxxx 200 in 2132ms
 ✓ Compiled in 305ms (762 modules)
 ✓ Compiled /api/download/schematic in 44ms (148 modules)
instance created
downloadTokens instance : [object Map]
Map(0) {}
 ⨯ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/...


We need more information. Where does this code snippet appear? Can you provide a [mre]? If this is in a React component, perhaps it should be using state.

I call the map into a nextjs handler
